# PHP S3 SDK putObject erro "invalid resource type"

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Hi I'm trying to transfer files with the PHP SDK but I receive a "Invalid resource type".

```
$client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
    'key' => $key,
    'secret' => $secret
));

try {
    $client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'bucket/uploads/photos',
        'Key' => 'example.jpg',
        'SourceFile' => '/absolute/path/to/example.jpg',
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ));
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tested the IAM user with the Amazon policy simulator and the user has access to putObject for that resource.

The SDK version is 2.6.15.

I also tested 'Hello world' in the 'Body' instead of 'SourceFile'. If I use body with plain text it works.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try through `Body` :

```
$client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'bucket/uploads/photos',
    'Key  ' => 'example.jpg',
    'Body' => fopen('/absolute/path/to/example.jpg','r'),
    'ACL' => 'public-read-write',
    'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
));
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know I could use this way too... I think my actual problem was the file permissions though..